# Selenium RC/Nunit/Firefox - Browser Crash on Click

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, nunit, selenium-rc

I am testing a complex web application using a test framework comprised of **C#, Nunit 2.5.10 and Selenium RC 2.24.1** (Switching to WebDriver is not an option unfortunately).

We recently overhauled our application UI/UX, so we have been systematically updating our tests to fit the new version.

Everything has been pretty smooth until we ran into an issue where our browser seems to randomly crash when running certain tests. We use **Firefox**(Chrome Driver) for testing, but have various versions installed on our test clients from **3.6 to 15.01**. The issue seems to be consistently reproducible on all browser versions running on **Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2**.

When the browser crashes it leaves behind a dialog which remains even after we run our clean up method which kills any open browser sessions in preparation for the next tests. Because this dialog sticks around, it keeps an RC server session alive which causes the next set of tests to hang.

I traced the tests down to the specific actions which are causing the crash, and it seems to always be a click event, but on various buttons within the application, and not always the same one. The buttons have nothing in common except that they all trigger a **javascript postback**. I was also able to trace one crash to a **postback event triggered by a drop down box selection**.

Our test framework is fairly complex and we have thousands of tests, so we have resorted to commenting the crashing tests just to keep the rest of the suite running.

We have been unable to simulate the crash with manual testing, even when following the exact path taken by the selenium test.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this, or ways to troubleshoot it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with intermittent failure of Selenium tests caused by the real time protection on Microsoft Security Essentials.  For me unchecking Turn on real-time protection in Settings | Real-time protection while I was running tests fixed the issue.  Try disabling your anti virus while running tests and see if that solves your problem.  Apparently the actions taken by Selenium can be interpreted as virus activity.